# Como exibir uma lista do retorno do 'For' com JOptionPane sem que seja apresentado como linha a linha mostrado na imagem?

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class tabuada_v2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double numero;
        Double continuar;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
                        
            numero = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Esse é seu programa de Tabuada."+ "\n" + "\n" + "Você, pode utilizar número Inteiro ou utilizar Ponto(.) ao invés da virgula, para a sua tabuada." + "\n "  + "\n "+"Informe o número da tabuada: "));

                        for (float i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numero + " x " + i + " = " + (numero * i) + "\n");
            
            
            continuar = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja continuar com sistema? (1)Sim ou (0)Não: "));
sc.close();             
            
        } while (continuar > 0);
    }}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já não fez a mesma pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/591261/como-eu-posso-formatar-retorno-do-for-em-2-ou-3-casas-utilizando-o-joptionpa

Comment: Considerando que [a pergunta já havia sido feita](/q/591261/70), o espaço de comentários foi desativado para evitar descentralização de informações - mas pode ser usado na postagem original.